# Restricting user to copy paste url in silverlight

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight

I have a Silverlight application and in web project i have a login.aspx; which authenticates an user and allows silverlight page to be opened. My problem is i need to disallow a user to copy the direct silverlight url and paste it. The user should follow the sequence all the time i.e Login then SL page.

How to prevent this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that each access to the page should check the provided log in details. If the user hasn't logged in, then there will be no log in details and so they will not gain access to the page.

There are several ways to achieve this. You could even implement your own custom authentication system without too much trouble - it just involves checking log in details before displaying any relevant pages. Alternatively, you can read more about the .NET authentication services in the [Walkthrough: Using Authentication Service with Silverlight Business Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942449(v=vs.91).aspx) page on MSDN.